# Mysql query GROUP BY where condition LIMIT 1

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "articles" on the database

articles :

```
id +++   writer_id    +++     title     ++++    text
----------------------------------------------------
1           1              some title        article for writer 1 
2           1              some title        article for writer 1 
3           2              some title        article for writer 2 
4           2              some title        article for writer 2 
5           2              some title        article for writer 2
6           3              some title        article for writer 3
```

I need a query to get the latest articles from the table BUT just ONE article for each Writer

depends on the rows above the query should get just 3 rows :
each article owns by ONE writer

```
2           1              some title        article for writer 1 
5           2              some title        article for writer 2
6           3              some title        article for writer 3
```

php

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles
WHERE writer_id = ???? ;
order by id desc limit 10
```

thanks in advance  : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and sweet:

```
SELECT MAX(id), writer_id, title, text FROM articles GROUP BY writer_id;
```

Comment: This won't actually correlate the correct article text and title with the correct dates (but it will appear to work with the example data given here because the titles and text are repeated).  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7972973/351048 for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` will allow you to get the last article written by each author, and have them ordered properly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles
WHERE writer_id = ????
GROUP BY writer_id
HAVING id = MAX(id)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get the latest *article id* per writer:

```
SELECT * FROM articles
WHERE id in
(
    SELECT MAX(id) id, writer_id
    FROM articles
    GROUP BY writer_id
)
```